# Multiple inclusions of same files with different preprocessor settings for creation and assigning of variables

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, iar

I have been running in the an error in regards to creation of variables through the Preprocessor. AppObjdict is loaded with objdict_frm.h and AppObjdict.h together with a define that controls the behavior of macros in objdict_frm.h. AppObjdict.h is an separate addition to objdict_frm.h. But the IAR compilers throws: Error[Pe169] expected a declaration

```
**AppObjdict.c**

#define PROTOTYPES
 #include "objdict_frm.h"   
 #include "AppObjdict.h"
#undef PROTOTYPES


s_List_Element OD_init[]=
{
#define SET_OD
#include "objdict_frm.h"
#include "AppObjdict.h"
#undef  SET_OD
    0xffff, 0, NULL
};
        
#define RESERVE_RAM
#include <objdict_frm.h>
#include "AppObjdict.h"
#undef  RESERVE_RAM

void Init_Canop_Structures(int* pNetCfg_p)
{
  pNetCfg_p=7;
#define INIT_RAM
  #include <objdict_frm.h>
  #include "AppObjdict.h"
#undef  INIT_RAM
  return;
}
```

The content is of objdict_frm.h is loaded correctly as well as all the macros that are used for creation of the variables.
Yet the content of AppObjdict.h is not loaded and throws and error on the SET_OD section of the initialization. Guards have been removed from both objdict_frm.h and AppObjdict.h, because the same file need to be ran through several times. Why can the data from AppObjdict.h not pass the compiler?

```
**objdict_frm.h**

#ifdef PROTOTYPES
#define CREATE(a,b)             extern a b[];
#define CREATE_INDEX_VAR(a,b)   extern u_Subindex_Value   a[];
#define CREATE_INDEX_FULL(a,b)  extern s_SubIndex_Element a[];
#define CREATE_INDEX_ROM(a,b)
#endif

#ifdef RESERVE_RAM
 #define CREATE(a,b)             a b[sizeof( b##_init ) / sizeof( a )];
 #define CREATE_INDEX_VAR(a,b)   u_Subindex_Value   a[sizeof( a##_init ) / sizeof( s_SubIndex_Element)];
 #define CREATE_INDEX_FULL(a,b)  s_SubIndex_Element a[sizeof( a##_init ) / sizeof( s_SubIndex_Element)];
 #define CREATE_INDEX_ROM(a,b)
#endif

#ifdef INIT_RAM
 #define CREATE_INDEX_FULL(a,b)  memcpy((BYTE*)a,(BYTE*)a##_init,sizeof(a));
 #define CREATE_INDEX_VAR(a,b)   initram_var_func(&a[0],&a##_init[0].Subindex_Value,sizeof(a##_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element));
 #define CREATE(a,b)             memcpy((BYTE*)b,(BYTE*)b##_init,sizeof(b));
 #define CREATE_INDEX_ROM(a,b)
#endif

#ifdef SET_OD
 #define CREATE(a,b)
 #define CREATE_INDEX_FULL(a,b)  b,(sizeof(a##_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),a,
 #define CREATE_INDEX_VAR(a,b)   b,(sizeof(a##_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),a##_init,
 #define CREATE_INDEX_ROM(a,b)   b,(sizeof(a##_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),a##_init,
#endif

CREATE_INDEX_FULL (s_dummy_8,                   0x0005)
```

```
**AppObjdict.h**

CREATE_INDEX_FULL (s_boardId,                   0x0012);

#undef  CREATE
#undef  CREATE_INDEX_VAR
#undef  CREATE_INDEX_FULL
#undef  CREATE_INDEX_ROM
```

Note: the amount of CREATE_INDEX_FULL has been reduced as the same operation is done hundreds of times

Thanks in advance

removed guards from the included files
changed marcos slightly and cleaned them up

Comment: Don't you have a feeling that using so many `#macros` creates hard to maintain, hard to debug, hard to fix code? Did you consider writing simple, readable, clear, easy-to-fix code with the least possible amount of macros?  I do not understand why you need macros. Just write the code that the macros expand to. It's much simpler that way. `But the IAR compilers throws: Error[Pe169] expected a declaration` Please post the full error message including any `note:` or `in expansion of` from the compiler. To which line does the error refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something screwy about `iar`. I'm on a linux x86_64 PC and I'm unable to reproduce your problem.

I added some tracing with a `SHOWME` macro.

From the output (at the bottom), `AppObjDict.h` *is* being included *multiple* times (*without* any sort of `#ifndef` guard or `#pragma once`).

At a guess ... If you still have issues using my versions, `iar` defaults to adding an implicit `#pragma once` to each `.h` it tries to include. If so, that's [IMO] bad/dumb.

---

objdict_frm.h:

```
// **objdict_frm.h**

SHOWME(objdict_frm_h_ENTER)

#ifdef PROTOTYPES
SHOWME(objdict_frm_h_PROTO)
#define CREATE(a,b)             extern a b[];
#define CREATE_INDEX_VAR(a,b)   extern u_Subindex_Value   a[];
#define CREATE_INDEX_FULL(a,b)  extern s_SubIndex_Element a[];
#define CREATE_INDEX_ROM(a,b)
#endif

#ifdef RESERVE_RAM
SHOWME(objdict_frm_h_RESERVE)
 #define CREATE(a,b)             a b[sizeof( b##_init ) / sizeof( a )];
 #define CREATE_INDEX_VAR(a,b)   u_Subindex_Value   a[sizeof( a##_init ) / sizeof( s_SubIndex_Element)];
 #define CREATE_INDEX_FULL(a,b)  s_SubIndex_Element a[sizeof( a##_init ) / sizeof( s_SubIndex_Element)];
 #define CREATE_INDEX_ROM(a,b)
#endif

#ifdef INIT_RAM
SHOWME(objdict_frm_h_INIT)
 #define CREATE_INDEX_FULL(a,b)  memcpy((BYTE*)a,(BYTE*)a##_init,sizeof(a));
 #define CREATE_INDEX_VAR(a,b)   initram_var_func(&a[0],&a##_init[0].Subindex_Value,sizeof(a##_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element));
 #define CREATE(a,b)             memcpy((BYTE*)b,(BYTE*)b##_init,sizeof(b));
 #define CREATE_INDEX_ROM(a,b)
#endif

#ifdef SET_OD
SHOWME(objdict_frm_h_OD)
 #define CREATE(a,b)
 #define CREATE_INDEX_FULL(a,b)  b,(sizeof(a##_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),a,
 #define CREATE_INDEX_VAR(a,b)   b,(sizeof(a##_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),a##_init,
 #define CREATE_INDEX_ROM(a,b)   b,(sizeof(a##_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),a##_init,
#endif

CREATE_INDEX_FULL (s_dummy_8,                   0x0005)

SHOWME(objdict_frm_h_EXIT)
```

---

AppObjdict.h:

```
// **AppObjdict.h**

SHOWME(AppObjdict_h_ENTER)
CREATE_INDEX_FULL (s_boardId,                   0x0012);
SHOWME(AppObjdict_h_EXIT)

#undef  CREATE
#undef  CREATE_INDEX_VAR
#undef  CREATE_INDEX_FULL
#undef  CREATE_INDEX_ROM
```

---

AppObjdict.c:

```
// **AppObjdict.c**

#define SHOWME(_who)        SHOWME_ ## _who

SHOWME(AppObjdict_c_ENTER)

#define PROTOTYPES
SHOWME(AppObjdict_c_PROTO)
 #include "objdict_frm.h"
 #include "AppObjdict.h"
#undef PROTOTYPES

s_List_Element OD_init[]=
{
#define SET_OD
SHOWME(AppObjdict_c_OD)
#include "objdict_frm.h"
#include "AppObjdict.h"
#undef  SET_OD
    0xffff, 0, NULL
};

#define RESERVE_RAM
SHOWME(AppObjdict_c_RESERVE)
#include <objdict_frm.h>
#include "AppObjdict.h"
#undef  RESERVE_RAM

void Init_Canop_Structures(int* pNetCfg_p)
{
  pNetCfg_p=7;
#define INIT_RAM
SHOWME(AppObjdict_c_INIT)
  #include <objdict_frm.h>
  #include "AppObjdict.h"
#undef  INIT_RAM
  return;
}

SHOWME(AppObjdict_c_EXIT)
```

---

I ran it through `cpp` with `cpp -I. -P AppObjdict.c > out`

Here is the output:

```
SHOWME_AppObjdict_c_ENTER
SHOWME_AppObjdict_c_PROTO
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_ENTER
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_PROTO
extern s_SubIndex_Element s_dummy_8[];
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_EXIT
SHOWME_AppObjdict_h_ENTER
extern s_SubIndex_Element s_boardId[];;
SHOWME_AppObjdict_h_EXIT
s_List_Element OD_init[]=
{
SHOWME_AppObjdict_c_OD
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_ENTER
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_OD
0x0005,(sizeof(s_dummy_8_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),s_dummy_8,
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_EXIT
SHOWME_AppObjdict_h_ENTER
0x0012,(sizeof(s_boardId_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),s_boardId,;
SHOWME_AppObjdict_h_EXIT
    0xffff, 0, NULL
};
SHOWME_AppObjdict_c_RESERVE
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_ENTER
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_RESERVE
s_SubIndex_Element s_dummy_8[sizeof( s_dummy_8_init ) / sizeof( s_SubIndex_Element)];
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_EXIT
SHOWME_AppObjdict_h_ENTER
s_SubIndex_Element s_boardId[sizeof( s_boardId_init ) / sizeof( s_SubIndex_Element)];;
SHOWME_AppObjdict_h_EXIT
void Init_Canop_Structures(int* pNetCfg_p)
{
  pNetCfg_p=7;
SHOWME_AppObjdict_c_INIT
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_ENTER
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_INIT
memcpy((BYTE*)s_dummy_8,(BYTE*)s_dummy_8_init,sizeof(s_dummy_8));
SHOWME_objdict_frm_h_EXIT
SHOWME_AppObjdict_h_ENTER
memcpy((BYTE*)s_boardId,(BYTE*)s_boardId_init,sizeof(s_boardId));;
SHOWME_AppObjdict_h_EXIT
  return;
}
SHOWME_AppObjdict_c_EXIT
```

Comment: I would say, in the `AppObjDict.h` macro `CREATE_INDEX_FULL (s_boardId, 0x0012);` should not have that semicolon at the end. It causes multiple times a double semicolon and in the structure initialization an invalid semicolon `0x0012,(sizeof(s_boardId_init)/sizeof(s_SubIndex_Element)),s_boardId,; <--`

Comment: @kesselhaus Yes, that looks wrong. I did _only_ the `cpp` output because that's what OP was talking about. It might be that it's just a compilation/syntax error rather than a `cpp` issue. I also do a _lot_ of these `.h` repeated includes for just the same reason (e.g. To do "templates" in C) and I often make initial mistakes like the one you found.